# Converting R to Python Function

Tags: python

Trying to convert below R function to python function:

```
    forecast_pv_case_1 <- function(model, assump, from, to, base_pv, age) {
  total_pv <- reduce((from:to), function(a, n) {
    decay1 <- (model[['a']] * (n ^ model[['b']]))
    decay2 <- (model[['a']] * (ceiling(age / 7) ^ model[['b']])) 
    growth <- ((1 + (assump[['pv_growth']] / 4)) ^ ceiling(n / 7)) 
    pv_n <- ((base_pv / decay2) * decay1 * growth)
    return(
      a + round(pv_n,0)
    )
  },.init = 0)
  return(
    total_pv
  )
```

Below is what I have converted but receiving syntax error.

```py
    def forecast_pv_case_1(model, assump, from_, to, base_pv, age):
    def total_pv(from_,to,a,n):
                 decay1 = (model[['a']] * (n ^ model[['b']])) 
                 decay2 = (model[['a']] * (np.ceil(age / 7) ^ model[['b']])) 
                 growth = ((1 + (assump[['pv_growth']] / 4)) ^ np.ceil(n / 7)) 
                 pv_n = ((base_pv / decay2) * decay1 * growth)
                 return(a + round(pv_n,0)),.init = 0
    return(total_pv)
```

I don't know R so any help on above is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just so you are aware, there is a package called rpy2 which lets Python interface with R, so if you have a lot of existing R code this might be an alternative to converting it all to Python - https://rpy2.github.io/

Comment: You changed the header syntax from R to Python, inserted `np.ceil` for `ceiling`, and changed the assignment operators, but have otherwise copied and pasted more or less verbatim, which is why things aren't working. `[[` is for lists in R, but will produce a TypeError in Python, and `^` means one thing in R and another in Python. The return statement in your inner function is a proper return statement, followed by a comma, followed by the `.init` parameter that actually belongs to `purrr::reduce`. Beyond that parameter, I don't see any trace of `reduce`'s functionality in the Python function.

Comment: There are a number of other errors. I'm afraid this question is too broad in its current form, as any answer would need to include explanations of basic syntax, operators, data structures, etc. for both R and Python. Can you maybe add more focus?

Comment: @gersht - You are correct, there may be many syntax errors in this because I'm unaware of R syntax converting to python. Just started doing couple of days ago in understanding R and converting to python. My goal is to convert this R function to python function.